# Put bounties on other people's questions?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

For whatever reason when I go to other people's questions that are eligible for bounty it appears that I can put bounty on them when they are not my own questions!

Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/