# How to manually award bounty on another persons question?

Tags: support, bounties

Need to know how to award bounty on another persons question and how it helps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps,

- Click on `start a bounty` link, it will show you following dialog,

  > [image]
- Select the bounty point you want to set and then click on `Next` Button, it will show you below dialog box,

> [image]

- From this dialog select the last option `Reward existing answer` and click on `Next` button, it will show you following dialog

> [image]

- In this dialog box you can give any custom message you want however it is optional. Then click on `Set Bounty` button and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Look right under the question body. You will see a small link  <kbd>set bounty</kbd> . Click on it.

After that, follow the steps given in the popup.

How it helps is covered in the question : [Put bounties on other people's questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54323/put-bounties-on-other-peoples-questions)