# What is the reasoning behind the ability to put bounty on somebody else's question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

If I set a bounty on another user's question, how does it help me personally?

I read another question on Meta, *[Put bounties on other people's questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54323/)*, but it's just asking if it's a bug or a feature and not explaining the reason behind it.

Comment: Please consider adding comment if you think this post can be improved.!!! :/

Comment: The downvotes here mean people think your question is too triviail. I'm not one of them, hope to post answer soon.

Comment: I took the liberty first to edit in order to make it more clear what is the actual question here, hope you don't mind?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reasons to put a bounty on another user's question include...

- You really, really want/need to know the answer to a question somebody else asked (asking duplicates is a no-no on Stack Overflow!)
- You think somebody else asked a good question and it should be answered (even though you won't profit from it yourself)
- You think a question should be answered well so you can close other, new questions as duplicate of it (many questions get asked thousands of times and having *one* quality resource for it makes a lot of sense)
- You want to reward an existing answer to somebody else's questions with a few rep points because...

  - ...you think it's a great answer
  - ...you want to thank the user for something they did for me
  - ...you want to hit on a user and leave a good first impression ("oh, what a generous guy/gal! I wonder whether they're single.")
- You want to get hold of the "altruist" badge

Comment: Well said, saved me the need to post my own answer. Worth to mention [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1409/152859) which triggered the whole thing. :)

Comment: Maynot be a honest reason, but the intention may include this too : "If it's for the first time, your will earn a new badge too, *Altruist*" :-)

Comment: @MicRo that's a very good point. Added.

Comment: one question what about booster batch if i share other question?

Comment: @Reshma yup, sharing any question counts, not only your questions

Comment: @Pekka웃 sorry for asking again, who will be awarded badge?

Comment: @Reshma the person who did the sharing. The "share" link contains your user ID so the system knows who to reward

Comment: @Pekka웃 thank you for your response, so if i share other questions also, then i will be awarded booster badge if it was visited by 300 unique IP addresses?

Comment: @Reshma yes. ---

Comment: @Pekka웃 so helpful responses

Comment: Or, in my case once, [you saw a great question with no activity, but it was something you were never going to use anytime soon, but the information is valuable in case you do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516476/long-double-gcc-specific-and-float128).